# recursive function calling in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

Whats the difference between

```
return(checkBst(root->left, minvalue, root) && checkBst(root->right, root, maxvalue));
```

and

```
return(checkBst(root->left, minvalue, root));
return(checkBst(root->right, root, maxvalue));
```

My whole programme looks like this

```
bool checkBst(node *root, node * minvalue, node * maxvalue){
    if(root == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    if((minvalue && root->data <= minvalue->data) || (maxvalue && root->data >= maxvalue->data)){
        return false;
    }
    return(checkBst(root->left, minvalue, root) && checkBst(root->right, root, maxvalue));
    // return(checkBst(root->left, minvalue, root));
    // return(checkBst(root->right, root, maxvalue));
}
```

Comment: Optimization mostly, the first solution will not call checkBst(root->right) if checkBst(root->left) already evaluates to false. The compiler can do this because the expression will evaluate to false regardless. (Similar for OR, if left hand side already is true, then right hand side will not be evaluated)

Comment: Learn about [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be frank, you cannot have a return for each of the function calls. This is because return is the last statement executed in a function before the control is given back to the calling function.

In your case, the second function is NEVER called. So, if your first function returns true, it never calls the 2nd function. Had the 2nd function result been false, the answer you get will be erroneous.

You still need to have a return statement at the end of both statements and capture the value returned by the functions.

I mean this statement:

```
return(checkBst(root->left, minvalue, root) && checkBst(root->right, root, maxvalue));
```

is equal to:

```
ret1 = checkBst(root->left, minvalue, root);
if(ret1)
    return checkBst(root->right, root, maxvalue);
else
    return false;
```

Recursion is not about putting everything in one line. That is just a coding style. The Comment by Pepijn Kramer and Some programmer dude talk about the optimization that you can get with writing in the same line. If the 1st half is false, you don't need to evaluate the 2nd half and that saves computation time and energy.

Recursion is about doing repetitive tasks by calling the same function within itself and using the result of it to give the final result.

In your case, Initially you send the whole tree. Then you divide the problem into 2 halves by calling the function for each of the sub-trees.

In each function call you take care of the terminal conditions. That is the first and second lines that you have. Those are the only cases where you don't call more functions. You are getting a return value.

Now, this return value should be propagated back to the calling function

Comment: *this statement ... is equal to ...* - This is not true because of short-curcuiting.

Comment: I think I meant to add by logic but missed it. I also mentioned about the optimization later

Comment: No, even by logic it is *very* different. Consider: `bool foo(int* i) { return i != nullptr && *i > 0; }`. Would you call short-curcuiting here an "optimization"? The very correctness of this code is based on short-curcuiting.

Comment: In this case, short-circuiting is only an optimization. I am not saying short-circuiting is always about optimization. It is not a different logic. I changed the answer to include the short-circuiting but I still say the logic is the same.